# Questions regarding normal subgroup definitions and equivalence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

In the Group Theory class I'm taking we were given the following definition for a normal subgroup:

1. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ iff $\forall a \in G$, $a^{-1}Ha=H$.

Then we proved that the definition and the following are equivalent:

2. $\forall a \in G$, $aH=Ha$
3. $\forall a,b \in G$, $HaHb=Hab$

I have a few questions regarding all of this:

I. In class we proved that $1 \iff 2$ and $2 \iff 3$, but I wanted to try something different to prove the equivalence: $1 \Rightarrow 2$, $2 \Rightarrow 3$ and $3 \Rightarrow 1$.
I've already managed to prove that $1 \Rightarrow 2$ and $2 \Rightarrow 3$, however I can't seem to prove that $3 \Rightarrow 1$ and would greatly appreciate a hint in how to proceed.

II. On my first attempt at proving that $1 \Rightarrow 2$ I mistakenly used that $a^{-1}Ha=H$ implies that $a^{-1}ha=h$ for any $h \in H$, I now know that this is not true. Considering that $a^{-1}Ha$ and $H$ are both subgroups of $G$ and they are the same subgroup (because $a^{-1}Ha=H$), then does that mean that $a^{-1}Ha$ is, in a sense, a rearrangement of $H$?

III. When proving that $2 \Rightarrow 3$, I realised that when I proved that $Hab \subset HaHb$ the only thing I needed was that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, that leads me to believe that $Hab \subset HaHb$ happens as long as $H$ is a subgroup (regardless if $H$ is normal or not). I then tried to do some examples to check and the claim did hold, however I do wonder if my examples are too easy. So, my question is: is the claim indeed true or did I make a mistake somewhere in the proof I made?

IV. When looking for some hints in how to prove that $3 \Rightarrow 1$ I realised that $3$ doesn't seem to be a common definition of a normal subgroup, or at least not as common as $1$ and $2$, is there a special reason why?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Yes, the function $h\mapsto aha^{-1}$ defined on $H$ is a permutation of $H,$ which is the term mathematicians use for a “rearrangement.”

Comment: For (III), you only need $1\in H$ to get $Hab\subset HaHb.$ This is because $Ha1b=Hab,$ and $Ha1b\subset HaHb.$ So you don’t even need $H$ a subgroup.

Comment: Mostly, the third is not used as a definition because it is harder to verify for subgroups- it require three cosets of $H.$ But the third is ultimately the big reason we like normal subgroups (it lets us define the product of cosets, making the quotient $G/H$ a group.)

Comment: Thank you @ThomasAndrews! That clears a lot of things up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3\implies 1$: Suppose that for all $a,b\in G$, $HaHb=Hab$.  We want to show that $gHg^{-1}=H$ for all $g\in G$.

Note that $ghg^{-1}=1ghg^{-1}\in HgHg^{-1} = Hgg^{-1} = H$ for all $h\in H$. Thus, $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ for all $g\in G$. Thus, we also have $g^{-1}Hg\subseteq H$, and we get equality.

Yes, conjugation by $a$ is a bijection, so if $a$ normalizes $H$, then it just permutes its elements.

Comment: Wait, you proved that $gHg^{-1} \subset H$, how does that imply that $H \subset gHg^{-1}$ or $H \subset g^{-1}Hg$?

Comment: @Blue I proved that $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ *for every* $g\in G$. So it also holds for $g^{-1}$, hence $g^{-1}Hg\subseteq H$. Now multiply on the left by $g$ and on the right by $g^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks a lot.