# Given $H \lhd G$ and $G/H$ is abelian then the derived group $G'$ or $[G,G]$ satisfies $G'\subseteq H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, derived-subgroup

> Given $H \lhd G$ and $G/H$ is abelian then the derived group $G'$ or $[G,G]$ satisfies $G'\subseteq H$

I've approached this problem the following way:

As $H$ is abelian then given $a,b \in G$,

$$\begin{align}
aH \cdot bH=bH \cdot aH &\Rightarrow (a \cdot b)H= (b \cdot a)H\\
& \Rightarrow H=(b^{-1}\cdot a^{-1}\cdot b \cdot a)H
\end{align}$$

This means that for any given $a,b \in G$ and $h \in H$ we have that $(b^{-1}\cdot a^{-1}\cdot b \cdot a)\cdot h \in H$

Making $h:=1_G$ we have that $(b^{-1}\cdot a^{-1}\cdot b \cdot a) \in H$   $\forall a,b \in G$

Therefore, as $H$ is a subgroup $\langle \{b^{-1}\cdot a^{-1}\cdot b \cdot a: a,b\in G\}\rangle \subseteq H$ thus $G'\subseteq H$

My problem with this is that I don't use the condition $H \lhd G$ and this is usually a bad sign in a proof. I would appreciate if anyone could verify this proof or help me see where its wrong

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $H$ is not normal in $G$, then $G/H$ is not well-defined.

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: "As $H$ is abelian..." Actually you are using that $G/H$ is abelian, not $H$ ($H$ need not be abelian). And as noted, this requires $G/H$ to be a group, which in turn requires that [$H$ be normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4413487/742).

Comment: A slightly more complete statement is "For a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, the following are equivalent: (1) $H$ is normal in $G$ and $G/H$ is abelian; (2) $G' \le H$."